# Creación de Base de datos y Lectura con python

Tags: python, sql

necesito ayuda para poder conocer los pasos a seguir para el proyecto que os resumo a continuación.
Se quiere crear una base de datos donde se recopile toda la información de proyectos realizados de una empresa. Por poner un ejemplo; en dichos proyectos se encuentran diferentes estudios con características concretas que pueden ser relacionadas con parámetros de comportamiento en diferentes ámbitos.
Una vez creada y reunida toda la información de dichos proyectos, se quiere que, a través de otra herramienta, pudiendo ser Python, para futuros proyectos con nuevos estudios, con la memoria (y experiencia) generada en la recopilación de base de datos creada, se pueda acceder a ellos de una forma más rápida de modo que si en nuevos estudios de nuevos proyectos se repite algún patrón conocido anteriormente, se pueda clasificar rápidamente ese tipo de comportamiento.

Por más que busco en internet no encuentro nada, sólo tutoriales básicos acerca de SQLite3, y cómo crear bases de datos desde cero, pero no es eso lo que busco. También lo que encuentro de python es tan básico que no puedo encontrar el camino para hallar qué hacer para el problema que os he propuesto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema está más allá de tus presentes habilidades. Aprende Python, aprende BBDD. En un 2-3 años podrás encontrar tú mismo la solución.

Comment: Empieza con un CRUD sencillo, así aprendes como funcionan los frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso https://www.heidisql.com/ para crear la base de datos y gestionarla.

Luego tienes que instalar un conector. Bien para Anaconda, bien para Pycharm según uses un entorno o cualquier otro.

Luego en tu programa importas la libreria:
import mysql.connector as mariadb

En la clase modelo tengo varios metodos para conectar, leer, grabar, actualizar, borrar, etc.

```
class Modelo:
def __init__(self):
    self.db = mariadb.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', user='root', 
password='42', database='database')
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
def conexion_db(self):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT VERSION()')
        self.db_sts_msg = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.db.commit()
        self.db_sts = True
        return True
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts = False
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        return False

def lee_uno(self, sql, val):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.db_registro = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if self.db_registro:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        return False
    def crea_tabla(self, sql):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.db_ultimo = self.cursor.lastrowid
        self.db_sts_msg = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.db.commit()
        return True
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        return False

def inserta(self, sql, val):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.db_ultimo = self.cursor.lastrowid
        self.db_sts_msg = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.db.commit()
        return True
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        print(e)
        return False

def actualiza(self, sql, val):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.db_registro = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.db_rows = self.cursor.rowcount
        self.db.commit()
        if self.db_rows:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        print(self.db_sts_msg)
        return False

def borra_tabla(self, sql):
    try:
        sql = 'drop table ' + sql
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.db.commit()
        return True
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        return False
```

Y luego tengo métodos para leer, grabar, etc. la base de datos en la Vista

class Vista(tk.Tk):

```
propietarioa = self.busca_propietario('Fulanito')

def busca_propietario(self,propietario):

    sql = "select * from propietarios where propietario ='" + str(propietario) + "';"
    if self.modelo.lee_uno(sql, ''):
        return self.modelo.db_registro[0]
    else:
        sql = "insert into propietarios(propietario) VALUES ('" + str(propietario) + "');"
        if self.modelo.inserta(sql, ''):
            return self.modelo.db_ultimo
        else:return 0
```

También puedes crear las tablas directamente en Python:

```
    # Tabla propietarios
    self.vista.mensajea("Chequeando Tabla propietarios ... ", False, 'yellow', self.ahora())
    if not self.modelo.lee_uno('SELECT count(*) FROM propietarios', ''):
        self.vista.mensajea("No existe, creando .... ", False, 'red', self.ahora())
        self.modelo.crea_tabla('create table propietarios ('
                               'cod int(8) not null auto_increment, '
                               'propietario tinytext not null, '
                               'primary key (cod), '
                               'unique index cod (cod), '
                               'unique index propietario (propietario) ) '
                               'COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ENGINE=InnoDB;')
        self.vista.mensajea("Creada.", True, 'green', self.ahora())
    else:
        self.vista.mensajea("Ok.", True, 'green', self.ahora())
```

Luego ya puedes realizar busquedas de patrones, etc..